# Don't want remove wishlist items when click 'Add all to cart' button - magento

Tags: magento

I change in code follow this http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197868/
to keep items in wishlist when user add item to cart.
But If user add all to cart instead of each item. All product will be remove from wishlist. 
I want to keep it in wishlist. Have any know how to fix it?
I try to open app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Controller\Abstract.php and comment out lines 
$item->delete();
But nothing better.
I'd appriciate your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Tought about that too, but figured out that the deletion happens on line 108 in `Mage_wishlist_Controller_Abstract`

```
// Add to cart
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
    $addedItems[] = $item->
}
```

In your Wishlist the **$isOwner** is set to **true** and that's the reason why your items get removed.
set **$isOwner** is set to **false** to stop the items get removed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Step 1:**

While adding allitems from wishlist to cart, there is no way to rewrite abstract file. so copy the file from

> app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Controller\Abstract.php

to

> app\code\local\Mage\Wishlist\Controller\Abstract.php

Then find inside `Abstract.php`

```
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
        $addedItems[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

set `$isOwner` to `false`.Update the code as

```
$isOwner = false;
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
        $addedItems[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

**Step 2:**

While adding individual items from wishlist to cart.
Follow the below steps

Rewrite the `Mage_Wishlist_IndexController` to local codepool

Then find the code in the rewrited controller file

```
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
       $addedItems[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

Update the code as

```
$isOwner = false;
if ($item->addToCart($cart, $isOwner)) {
        $addedItems[] = $item->getProduct();
}
```

Now wislist items will retain even after add to cart.

Refer this [link](https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/keep-product-in-the-wishlist-after-adding-to-cart-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this instead of overwriting or editing a abstract core file like some comments suggest I instead did a rewrite of the Wishlist controller:

```
Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
```

If you look in the `cartAction` function on you will find the following line `$item->addToCart($cart, true);`. The second parameter being sent here decides if the item should be deleted from the wishlist or not. If you in your rewritten controller set this to false the items will persist in the wishlist even though you add them to your cart.